# How to use loop in this case?

Tags: c++

You are working in a university, and the head of the department assigned to you the task of writing a C++
program that allows students to enroll in courses. The program should also update courses information after
each enrollment, and issue the course table to the student. The student can enroll in maximum two courses. 
The program ends if the student entered the letter f or after enrolling in two courses. 
Assume that three courses are opened and their information
(course Id, course name, maximum number allowed in the course and the actual number of students 
registered in the course) are stored in a file .

I used this code but it didn't work

```
while(i<3)
{
    Infile>>courseID>>course_name>>max_number>>numofenrol;

    if((course_ID==user_courseID)&&(course_name==user_cname)&&(max_number>numofenrol))
            cout<<"you are enrolled in "<<course_name<<endl;


    if((course_ID==user_course)&&(course_name==user_name)&&(max_number==numofenrol))
         cout<<"course is full"<<endl;

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why so much whitespace?

Comment: I don't know i had some problems while editing the code!

Comment: _but it didn't work_ What didn't work? Did it compile? I see you have an `If` (notice the capital letter) and `Cout` (again, capital), neither of which will compile (assuming you mean `std::cout`).

Comment: I have [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36394147/6) to format your code, and change `While`, `If` and `Cout` to the actual keywords because I assumed those weren't the problem

Comment: I had an infinit loop that dosen't even give the right result

Comment: Explain what problem you are facing with, are you getting errors?